# Invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 error inserting text into database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, utf-8, nokogiri

I'm trying to implement the vignere cipher to my rich text. I am using Nokogiri to extract the innerHTML of a node and implementing the cipher on it.

My model is:

```
# Entry.rb
class Entry < ApplicationRecord
  include EntriesHelper
  before_save :encode_content
  validates :content, presence: true

  def encode_content
    html_content=Nokogiri::HTML(self.content)
    nodes=html_content.css('p')
    nodes.each do |node|
      child=[]
      node.traverse{|n| child << n}
      text=child.first.text
      encoded_text=vignere_encoding(text)
      child.first.content=encoded_text
      puts child,encoded_text
    end
    modified_html=html_content.to_html
    self.content=modified_html.split("body>")[1][1..-4]
    save!
  end
end
```

The helper function for this is:

```
#entries_helper.rb
module EntriesHelper
  def passphrase
    'cipher'.upcase
  end

  def coding(phrase)
    codes=Array.new(phrase.length)
    for i in 0...phrase.length
      codes[i]=phrase[i].ord-'A'.ord
    end
    codes
  end

  def vignere_encoding(input_str)
    stringish=input_str
    phrase=passphrase
    if not phrase
      return
    end
    code=coding(phrase)
    counter=0
    code_len=code.length
    for i in 0...stringish.length
      if counter>=code_len
        counter%=code_len
      end
      stringish[i]=(stringish[i].ord+code[counter]).chr
      counter+=1
    end
    return stringish
  end
end
```

Everything is working fine. The Vignere_encoding function is correctly returning the encoded string and while I'm trying to save the data to the database I'm getting

```
Invalid byte Sequence in UTF-8
```

Can someone tell me how to implement this?

Comment: Usually that means you've got junk data coming in. Focus on breaking this down into smaller problems. Does your cypher work on known-good text? If so, what's in the document you're trying to process?

Comment: i checked output of cipher its not returning any invalid literals.I tried scrub("") on output of cipher to eliminate invalid characters. still im getting this error.Even self.content.valid_encodingg? gives me true

Comment: These things are normally better broken down into unit tests (e.g. `Test::Unit`) so you can verify each step is working. Is it possible that your `.chr` call is introducing characters > 127 in value? That can be problematic.

Comment: char value is not going beyond 127 here. I checked with unit tests also its also giving failure to this

Comment: What version of Ruby are you running? http://stackoverflow.com/q/28390653/128421

Comment: Is Ruby complaining or the database? What happens if you don't try to insert the data, just process it? It's not really a Nokogiri problem if you are correctly gathering the data you need, though your code looks very inefficient. Fixing that would be a separate question though.

Answer (score 0):

try adding this line on top of  entry.rb

`# encoding: UTF-8`

my doubt is with content getting saved after doing split

Comment: still no use. After split i checked encoding and is returing UTF-* as its encoding

Comment: [Ruby has defaulted to UTF-8 since v2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28390653/128421)